# What is the difference between phylogenetic tree "construction" and "reconstruction"?

Tags: evolution, terminology, phylogenetics

When I look through papers, there are two terms

1. Phylogenetic tree construction
2. Phylogenetic tree "Re"construction

What is the difference between phylogenetic tree "construction" and "reconstruction" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference! In both cases, they refer to the building of a phylogenetic tree from data.

The expression 'phylogenetic tree construction' is less common.